# How to get a stylecop ruleset trough nuget in a .net standard project

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-standard, stylecop

We are trying to provide a nuget package for all our projects with a stylecop ruleset.
We get the files in the project but the ruleset is not applied to our projects. It still uses the minimimumrecomended.ruleset.

what we have now is:

Custom.stylecop.props

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>Custom.StyleCop.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

custom.stylecop.targets

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\Content\stylecop.json">
      <Link>stylecop.json</Link>
    </AdditionalFiles>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Custom.stylecop.nuspec

```
<contentFiles>
    <files include="Content/stylecop.json" buildAction="EmbeddedResource" />
</contentFiles>
....
<files>
    <file src="build\**" target="build" />
    <file src="Content/stylecop.json" target="contentFiles" />
</files>
```

Does anyone have any idee or an example on github or so where we can find an example because we could not find any.

Comment: Unfortunatly No we stopped the project for now and are planning to reinvest time in 1 to 2 months. When we find a werking solution I will post it here.

Comment: Joey, sorry for deleting my earlier comment. Found this solution below which is working for me right now. Thank you for getting back so soon!

Comment: Joey, when you get the chance can you try out to see if response below solves the issue for you?  Thank you

Comment: I am going back to work on thursday I Will test if it works then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We solved the issue with the following:

CodeAnalysis.props

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\CodeAnalysis.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\stylecop.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

CodeAnalysis.nuspec

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>CodeAnalysis</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <description>Roslyn analyzers, rule sets and additional configuration to be used for Code Analysis</description>
        <authors></authors>
        <owners></owners>

        <dependencies>
          <dependency id="Stylecop.Analyzers" version="1.0.2" />
        </dependencies>
    </metadata>
    <files>
      <file src="stylecop.json" />
      <file src="CodeAnalysis.ruleset" />
      <file src="CodeAnalysis.props" target="build" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 2):

In our Xamarin.Forms projects the fix was a manual process of editing the .NET Standard `.csproj` file. If there's a better way, please let me know!

1. First, open your .NET Standard project in a text editor (_Notepad++)
2. Then add the `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet> ... </CodeAnalysisRuleSet>` inside a `<PropertyGroup>`.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\stylecop.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
</PropertyGroup>
```

3. (*optional*) If you want to access these files inside your project you can create an ItemGroup using `<AdditionalFiles ... />`.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="..\stylecop.json" />
    <AdditionalFiles Include="..\stylecop.ruleset" />
</ItemGroup>
```

#### Reference

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/compilers/Rule%20Set%20Format.md

Comment: This is a solution that works for that 1 project. We want that it automatically includes itself after installing the nuget package we created.

Comment: @joey, you and me both. Unfortunately, these are the cards we're dealt from the StyleCopAnalyzers group. Thankfully, with our Xamarin.Forms product we only have a handful of projects which need this manual massaging to reach our goal & it's been a huge help.  I appreciate the feedback